# How to override if of an object?

Tags: python, class, if-statement

I have  created a class A:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items

a=A([1,2])
```

I want to make it such that I can do `if a` to get True if there are items in the list and False otherwise. I couldn't find a way to do that. Overriding `__eq__` was for comparing the object with another.

Comment: Overwrite `__bool__(self)`!

Comment: You can also override the `__len__` method; that will be used if `__bool__` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override either the `__bool__` method or the `__len__` method (or both).

The `__bool__` method should return `True` or `False`; the `__len__` method should return an integer indicating how many items there are in the object, and in an `if` statement the object will be considered true if this is non-zero.

If both are defined, `__bool__` will be preferred for `if` statements; this can be useful if determining non-empty is faster than counting the elements, or if you need "empty but true" values.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items

    # implement either or both:
    
    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(self.items)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

See docs: [`__bool__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__)

Answer (score 0):

In programming terms, the `if a` in the expression `1 if a else 0` is known as truth value testing. If we look at the truth values of the built-in data types, the truth value will be `False` for `0` (int), `0.0` (float), `''` (str), '[]' or `list()`, `{}` or `dict()`, `()` or `tuple()`, `set()`, and of course `False` (bool). The result will be `True` otherwise.

Consider a class `A`, that has two attributes `a1` and `a2`, which can contain any data type. The instance of `A` should evaluate to `True` iff values of both the attributes are true. We have to implement the `__bool__` method of the class as shown,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.val1 = arg1
        self.val2 = arg2

    def __bool__(self):
        if self.val1 and self.val2:
            return True
        return False
```

Let's create some instances of this class, and check their truth values in a loop.

```
a1 = A(0, '')
a2 = A(1.3, [])
a3 = A('', [1, 2])
a4 = A(3, 'x')
for a in [a1, a2, a3, a4]:
    if a:
        print(a.val1, a.val2)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Output:

```
False
False
False
3 x
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).